# Hibernate JPA - deletar filhos dentro da lista

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
public class A implements Serializable {

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
   private List<B> bList;

}

public class B implements Serializable {
   @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private A a;
}
```

Com muito custo consegui fazer com que o Hibernate deixasse a foreign key da tabela A dentro de B como null em uma atualização de cadastro, porem com o orphanRemoval = true ele deveria deletar esses registros da tabela B, o que não esta acontecendo. Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Quando você carrega o `Object A` para ser deletado, a variável `List<B>` está preenchida? Pergunto pois o `FetchType.LAZY` faz com que a lista seja carregada somente caso for acessada.

Comment: Airton, consegue passar qual erro gera? Ou se esta conseguindo excluir o item A e o item B está ficando órfão?

Comment: a lsita é carregada certinha inclusive o hibernate ate deixa as foregin keys da tabela B como null, porem ele nao deleta essas linhas.... ele simplesmente deixa nullas e nao as apaga

Comment: Quando utilizava o Eclipse link so precisava por o @PrivateOwned q ele ja fazia tudo isso... porem agr no hibernate estou apanhando um pouco

Comment: Experimente mapear apenas um dos lados com `@JoinColumn` (o lado que tem a chave estrangeira) e no outro use o `mappedBy`. Do jeito que está aí, não há lado dominante do relacionamento e o Hibernante pode estar se perdendo.

Comment: anteriormente a tabela A tinha o mappedby no @OneToMany, e na tabela B estava o joinColumn, porem desta maneira nao estava nem setando como null a foreign key da tabela B  ao salvar o objeto da tabela A

Comment: Eu percebi q  se eu retirar o CascadeType.All e colocar apenas o CascadeType.Persiste e o CascadeType.Remove ele começa a remover de maneira correta. Porem ainda preciso do CascadeType.Merge e é ai que surge o problema. Se coloco o CascadeType.Merge, a remoção dos itens para de funcionar

Comment: Eu montei a mesma estrutura em um projeto desktop apenas com o hibernate e o meu projeto atual usa o springboot. No projeto desktop funciona perfeitamente, no projeto springboot da problema